# Should C:\Windows\System32\downlevel be in PATH

Tags: windows-10, dll

`api-ms-win-core-*.dll`s aren't resolved for some reason, for some DLLs I built with VS2022 and downloaded from [gstreamer](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/). I checked that with `depends.exe`. So I found out that those reside in `C:\Windows\System32\downlevel` and added it to PATH. However, `ext-ms-win-*.dll` still stay missing.

Should `C:\Windows\System32\downlevel` be in PATH?

I don't know if I messed up or not, please tell me if so.

Comment: Do you _actually_ have a problem? It is normal that these DLLs appear unresolved in Dependency Walker.

Comment: `depends.exe` erroneously will flag these files are missing even when they exist on the system, unless you are being told by Windows when you run the executable the files are missing, they actually exist on your system.

Comment: I do have problems loading it.

Comment: @xsb Better switch from *Depends* to [*Dependencies*](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies), an open source predecessor project that also works with newer Windows versions. (To install it, simply unzip the [latest release](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies/releases) it to a location of your choice.)

Comment: @Wolf I don't use it all that often, but yes, I've tried Dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not need to add this to your path but it wouldn't hurt anything if it were.

Windows knows where these files are and loads them as needed.  Also.. you will note that there aren't actually any files there.  They are all symlinks to files in the WinSxS folder.

If windows was unable to find these files, you would have much bigger problems.